# Raspberry + ROS + Servo

Tags: ros, servo, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

could anyone tell me some tutorial that teaches to control servoss via ROS installed in a Raspberry PI 3 (Ubuntu Mate

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248574/raspberry-+-ros-+-servo/) by [zpguedes](https://answers.ros.org/users/28389/zpguedes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working through this scenario. (See if this description is what you are attempting: http://elder.ninja/blog/p/6106)

Here are a few things which may make your life a bit easier:

Using Ubuntu server for RPi3 (rather than raspbian jessie) does make your query easier as you can install most packages using "apt-get install" and not need to "git" the source.

For PWM for positional control of standard servos as well as speed and direction control of continuous servos, you might check out the ros_i2cpwmboard package: https://gitlab.com/bradanlane/ros-i2cpwmboard/tree/master

Short description of end-to-end demonstration: http://elder.ninja/blog/p/6804 and accompanying video: https://vimeo.com/193201509

The documentation (http://bradanlane.gitlab.io/ros-i2cpwmboard/) for the ros_i2cpwmboard package gives simple test examples of rostopic() and rosservice(). The package supports controlling servos using direct PWM values, proportional values (-1.0 .. 1.0) and using geometry_msgs::Twist - the latter makes it easier to integrate with the turtlesim tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2016-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1